# How come when adding items into my list, inside a function, I need to put the element I'm adding in brackets?

Tags: python, function

```
def myfunc(*args):
    mylist = []
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            mylist += [num]
        else:
            pass
    return mylist
```

In the example above, (my list += [num]), how come num has to be inside brackets? Using Thonny I finally figured out I needed to do this, but I still don't know why. It seems like it should just add the num to the list (in my brain)? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like Python, can you add the Python tag?

Comment: It's concatenating two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `+=` to add it looks to combine variables of similar type, so num can be added to another `int` or `float`, but only `list` can be added to a list.

```
num = 2
num += 2
test = []
test += [4]
print(num, test)
```

Output:

```
4 [4]
```

You can also use `list.append()` if you want:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    mylist = []
    for num in args:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            mylist.append(num)
        else:
            pass
    return mylist
print(myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

This adds num as a element directly.